# Question on robots.txt with Disallow without colon

Tags: python, web-scraping, robots.txt

I recently started to work on a small webscraping task for my work and got somewhat familiar with the matter of `robots.txt`.

Here I recently found a website with a strange robots.txt file:

```
User-agent:*
Disallow
```

My understanding (supported by lots of example on different forums) of `robots.txt` is that `Disallow` command has to be qualified with the colon to have any effect on the crawlers that read the file. So from that I took that this webpage allows crawling by search engines.

On the other hand the line `User-agent:*` without any other lines is used to signal that the website allows full crawling. So why would it make sense to follow up with `Disallow`?

So all in All I am a little confused about the matter. I would appreciate some hints at what I am overlooking on this regard. 
The website is: http://de.vindecoder.pl/

Comment: This isn't really a programming questioning, [webmasters.se] might be a better place to ask about `robots.txt` format.

Comment: I think this is technically invalid syntax, but some web crawlers are permissive and treat it like `Disallow:`.

Answer (score 0):

This robots.txt is invalid. At least one `Disallow` line is required per record/block, and the colon is required to separate the field name from the field value.

So, technically, crawling of everything is allowed, as this is the default if no robots.txt exists.

The same would be the case if the site author added a `:`, as an empty `Disallow` value also means that crawling of everything is allowed:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```